# how to style the active thumbail in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In the following example, I want to give a background color and border for the active thumbnail - bootstrap carousel. There is an active class for the content items but the same is not there in the slider-thumbs. How can I add a class or style for the active thumbnail, Please help!

```
<!-- Main Area -->
            <div id="main_area">
                    <!-- Slider -->
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="span12" id="slider">
                                    <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="span8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                                                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                                                            <!-- Carousel items -->
                                                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                                    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one" /></div>
                                                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two" /></div>
                                                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three" /></div>
                                                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="3"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four" /></div>
                                                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="4"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five" /></div>
                                                                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="5"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six" /></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <!-- Carousel nav -->
                                                            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                                                            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span4" id="carousel-text"></div>

                                            <div style="display: none;" id="slide-content">
                                                    <div id="slide-content-0">
                                                            <h2>Slider One</h2>
                                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="slide-content-1">
                                                            <h2>Slider Two</h2>
                                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="slide-content-2">
                                                            <h2>Slider Three</h2>
                                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="slide-content-3">
                                                            <h2>Slider Four</h2>
                                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="slide-content-4">
                                                            <h2>Slider Five</h2>
                                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="slide-content-5">
                                                            <h2>Slider Six</h2>
                                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                    </div> <!--/Slider-->

                    <div class="row hidden-phone" id="slider-thumbs">
                            <div class="span12">
                                    <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
                                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                                            <li class="span2">
                                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0">
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one" />
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="span2">
                                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1">
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two" />
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="span2">
                                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2">
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three" />
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="span2">
                                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3">
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four" />
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="span2">
                                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4">
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five" />
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="span2">
                                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5">
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six" />
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    //Handles the carousel thumbnails
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
            var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });


    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
            var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've built your Carousel in a strange way.
The correct syntax is:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active left">
    <img alt="" class="" src="">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
<a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
```

So you won't have to manage transitions and so on, you just have to call the carousel on the div #myCarousel:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

Comment: thank you for ur comment, may be i was not clear, actually my idea is to build a content slider with tabs, here the thumbnails will act as the tabs. So need to find a way to make the active thumbnail highlighted.